# how to use flask-cache and memcached?

Tags: python, flask, memcached

an example for flask-cache with type "simple" below
but how can i use flask-cache with memcache ? I need ur help  thank you ：）

```
from flask import Flask
import random

# import the flask extension
from flask.ext.cache import Cache

app = Flask(__name__)

#import config setting
app.config["CACHE_TYPE"]="simple"

# register the cache instance and binds it on to your app 
app.cache = Cache(app)

@app.route("/")
@app.cache.cached(timeout=50,key_prefix="hello")  # cache this view for 30 seconds
def cached_view():
    a=random.randint(0,100)
    return str(a)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=5000, debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Answer (score 4):

:) I have solved this problem

**Q**:How to use memcached with flask-cache

**A**: just modify the cache type from "**simple**" to  "**memcached**",so easy

**attention:**

the most important thing you should notice is that  you should install libmemcached, pylibmc and python-dev. Also, **the  most important** is  that the version of libmemcached  should match the version of pylibmc,otherwise  it would be wrong when  **pip install pylibmc**

Comment: This seems like it will work in development with hosting through localhost, but what about in production? I currently have my app hosted on Heroku and want to use it through the web servers they use. Does this same process work for production?

Comment: doesn't work no matter what I try. And your description is too broad.