# python flask - how setup cache in nginx

Tags: python, caching, nginx, flask

I have a flask/nginx application and want to setup cache for 2 example url :

> ```
> 1. /category/apps-5.html
> 2. /product/test-product-sell-34690064571.html
> ```

my actual nginx config is this :

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443;
    ssl on;

    gzip on;
    gzip_min_length 1000;
    gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
    gzip_types text/plain text/html text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/javascript text/xml application/xml application/rss+xml application/atom+xml application/rdf+xml;
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";
    gzip_vary on;

    server_name  selfmarket.net www.selfmarket.net;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/selfmarket.net/cert.pem;        # path to your cacert.pem
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/selfmarket.net/privkey.pem;    # path to your privkey.pem

    fastcgi_param   HTTPS               on;
    fastcgi_param   HTTP_SCHEME         https;

    # Serve static files and uploads
    location ^~ /static/ {
        root /opt/master/app/;
    }


    location / {
        proxy_pass 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/';
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }
}
```

How i can setup simple cache (expiry in 3 minutes) for my example urls ? is my first time when use nginx .. im very beginer, thank you

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to cache on the backend. Flask has a simple cache or you can use memcache. See the examples [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/patterns/caching/), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25176813/how-to-use-flask-cache-and-memcached), and [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/9/).

Also, if you really need to speed things up, you can use the built-in memcache support that NGINX has (although this might be too complex). See this [doc](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_memcached_module.html) for more details.

If you really want NGINX to do the caching, check out the [official docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cache) on the `proxy_cache` module. There is also a guide available [here](https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-caching-guide/).